# MATLAB Data Structure with O(log(N)) Insertion, Deletion and Smallest Key Lookup?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to implement a queuing system with out of order insertion. Keys would correspond to the time members will leave the queue. Thus, by finding the smallest key, one can find the next member leaving the queue.

If it were c++, a map would solve it. MATLAB offers a structure named map, however it is a hashmap. It supports O(1) insertion and deletion however to find the smallest key one has to traverse all keys (O(N)). Another way would be using a vector as a queue. Smallest key would always be in the front, so access would be O(1). But in this scenario insertion to the middle of the queue would shift everything higher than the inserted key by one (O(N)).

So the question is:

- Is there a way to implement a map in MATLAB with similar behaviour to std::map?
- Is there another data structure that would give O(log(N)) performance for these operations?

Comment: Have you considered using `std::map` as-is via the  [MEX](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) interface, instead of re-implementing it?

Comment: There is a way to implement anything in MATLAB! Its Turing complete, like C++. You just need to implement it

Comment: You are looking for a priority queue, not a map. [This Q&A](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84725/simple-priority-queue) might be informative. Make sure to follow the links given as well!